How std::shared_ptr avoids completeness requirement for holding object?
How exactly std::shared_ptr handles incomplete type while std::unique_ptr can’t although they both have to deal with destruction of the holding object this way or another?
This code compiles just fine:
#include <memory>

class Somewhere;

struct C {
    std::shared_ptr<Somewhere> here;

    virtual ~C() = default;
};

int main()
{
    C c;
}

And if you replace std::shared_ptr with std::unique_ptr it won’t because the latter requires the holding type to be complete. I read explanations for this here, here, here and here and they say the same things that difference is in completeness requirements with nice clues for reasoning like “The reasons are obscure, having to do with a dynamic deleter vs a static deleter.”.
My assumption is that std::unique_ptr has to delete the object directly, owning it and std::shared_ptr somehow uses underlying level to place the destructor at the same module where std::make_shared where invoked and where the complete type exist because it needs to be created. And here comes the clue (The reasons are obscure, having to do with a dynamic deleter vs a static deleter) from above.
Anyway, looking into implementation of std::shared_ptr (MSVC version), I can’t see the way they handle it.
To put in a nutshell, the question is, in case the internal counter of std::shared_ptr drops to zero and it has to destruct the holding object, how it handles this it this specific pointer instance declared in the place where complete definition of holding object is inaccessible? How would it call the correct destructor?

And here

I'm too lazy to write a [tag:language-lawyer] answer, but long story short: shared_ptr stores deleter on the heap. You need definition of the type to construct a non-empty shared_ptr (unless you provide your own deleter). unique_ptr does not store deleter on the heap, it's part of the type. You don't need complete type to use unique_ptr, but you need complete type when you instantiate unique_ptr's destructor using default deleter. So you can only declare virtual ~C() in the class and define it later, where Somewhere definition is available. It can still be =default.

Additional caveat is that constructor might need to destruct members in case of exception

Technically, it's not std::unique_ptr that requires completness. The std::default_deleter needs to see the destructor. Provide a custom deleter  class argument to std::unique_ptr<T, D> and T can be incomplete, you nee D(the deleter) to be complete. std::shared_ptr doesn't have a deleter parameter in the type. You have to provide a deleter object to its constructor.
